# how to add property to @User.Identity or on claim to use in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't extend my Identity property in ASP.NET Core to use in a razor page, like this:

```html
<input type="text" class="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="@User.Identity.Id">
```

I try to use this, but it doesn't work:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager)
{
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Id", this.PublicId));
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Comment: CreateIdentityAsync is an ASP.NET MVC 5 method, it doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IClaimsTransformation

```
public class CustomClaimsTransformer:IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Id", Claim.Value you want));
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Add a claims transformation service to Startup.cs

```
 services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
```

Then try HttpContext.User.Claims to retrive the claims for the user, but it will work for sub-request instead of current login request.

```
 ViewData["Id"] = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Id").Value;
```

In Razor Page

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="@ViewData["Id"]">
```